# Spring boot 1.5.1 update static content 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This configuration works with boot 1.4.3.RELEASE
my static content works perfectly.
When i change the version to 1.5.1.RELEASE my static content returns
404 not found.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("file:" + Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), SGISSConfig.getInstance().getRepoFolder()) + "/");
}
```

Security Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/email/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();

}

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService users;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(users).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}
}
```

My static resources are /resources/static/**

## Edit

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFjUn.png)

Comment: Show actual tree of files and folders in your project, it could help.

Comment: the file tree is added on Folder Structure link